# IPFS private network setup not works

Tags: ipfs, private-network

I am trying to create a private network of IPFS with two nodes. Each node is an EC2 instance running on AWS. I generated swarm key and configure my node as follow:

```
"API": "/ip4/0.0.0.0/tcp/5001",
"Announce": [],
"Gateway": "/ip4/0.0.0.0/tcp/8080",
"NoAnnounce": [],
"Swarm": [
  "/ip4/0.0.0.0/tcp/4001",
  "/ip6/::/tcp/4001"
]
```

"Bootstrap": [
 "/ip4/172.31.25.195/tcp/4001/ipfs/QmaRpyg48RqdUwXVD84RSAd8hFvA2MNPvu3Z7yTxRFJKub"
  ]

Then I run "ipfs daemon" to start all nodes and "ipfs swarm peers" to list all connected peers. However, "ipfs swarm peers" doest list anything and I dont know what is the problem?

Comment: Can you share ipfs log entries? We should see the peers being added by bootstrap

Comment: Here is the log detail
{"error":"failed to bootstrap. dial to self attempted","event":"bootstrapError","peerID":"QmaRpyg48RqdUwXVD84RSAd8hFvA2MNPvu3Z7yTxRFJKub","system":"bootstrap","time":"2020-02-12T02:22:38.662775642Z"}

Comment: {"TraceID":8560678498726733911,"SpanID":6866367366277484649,"ParentSpanID":0,"Operation":"Provide","Start":"2020-02-12T02:23:15.868956846Z","Duration":91991,"Tags":{"system":"dht"},"Logs":[{"Timestamp":"2020-02-12T02:23:15.869011197Z","Fields":[{"Key":"cid","Value":"QmdL9t1YP99v4a2wyXFYAQJtbD9zKnPrugFLQWXBXb82sn"}]},{"Timestamp":"2020-02-12T02:23:15.869014096Z","Fields":[{"Key":"broadcast","Value":"true"}]},{"Timestamp":"2020-02-12T02:23:15.869047297Z","Fields":[{"Key":"error","Value":"failed to find any peer in table"}]}]}

Comment: Can you confirm your firewall rules? You need to add inbound TCP rules for ports 4001, 5001 and 8080 in your Security Groups from AWS Console.

Comment: My configuration is:

"Custom TCP    TCP                        4001                  0.0.0.0/0"  "
Custom TCP    TCP                        5001                  0.0.0.0/0"

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, actually it works now. This is problem with inbound TCP

Answer (score 1):

Its likely you need to add inbound TCP rules for ports 4001, 5001 and 8080 in your Security Groups from AWS Console.